# how to place text below background image using inline block property

Tags: html, css, background-image, display

hello i'm trying to put text below a background images. like here i want place two background images side by side and below each image i wanna place text. i have take one div class it has styles inline block property. so how i can do this with the help of or using inline block property.i have explained my problem as much as i can. if it is possible then please go through my fiddle link. i have tried by this properties but text is overlaping on the image i want that below the image also check similar questions no one has done with background image so please check out my code what i have tried it is given in the comment box. please help me thanks. :)

Comment: "if it is possible then please go through my fiddle link" - Where is the link?

Comment: my code:- https://jsfiddle.net/archan/a4c33ucd/

Comment: In your fiddle, you used 2 images: `background-image: url("../images/solution1.png");` - But they do not exist in the fiddle source. I suggest you fix this.

Comment: thats my local directory ohh just forget that and give me another example how i can do that

Comment: please if anyone know answer then give me reply

Comment: You cannot expect people to help you if you do not provide any code, and your fiddle does not work. Please do some work and edit your question.

Comment: Background images tend to be just that, in the background with stuff over the top of them, but using your fiddle, you could have something like `.image1,
.image2 {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.imgcontainer .imgcontainer p {
 padding-top: 100px;
}`

Comment: You can use remote images for your demos like `http://placehold.it/100x100/` as your local images won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a css property for your paragraph tag within your imgcontainer.

In my fiddle, I added the following :

```
.imgcontainer p {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

I also added a `background-size` to both of the background images. I used  `background-size: cover;` (I replaced the image urls with ones that I have in my image folder  on my website)

https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f0fsLd2h/ :Fiddle

Comment: yeah thanks @Rachel but when i write some less words in second div that is image 2 class it will align down little bit with the text and image see https://jsfiddle.net/archan/f0fsLd2h/3/ so how i can do the same thing but with maintaining same level

Comment: @Arch add a width and a height to the paragraph https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/wm671gya/ - updated fiddle . The width in the fiddle is 110 if you want it to be 110, you'll have to introduce a word-wrap like https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f0fsLd2h/6

Comment: yeah most welcome @Rachel can you do me one more help ? i wanna make two partitions one is for image and another is for text and in between two partitions draw vertical line and if it is possible then contents are align in center.

Comment: i have tried <hr width="1" size="200"> but this acquire whole area but using this can't use it's left or right side to put image or text

Comment: I just saw this. I'm eating but will post later. You should ask a different question..

Comment: @Arch i don't see a new question? I do have a job to do aswell as rep to gain.. post a new question and i'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope this was what you where looking for.

Here is a link to an updated fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4c33ucd/1/)

If you change te background-color to an image, it should still work

I simply added:

```
.imgcontainer p {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -90px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

To the paragraph

Comment: p will affect all paragraphs on the page. By using .imgcontainer p, it narrows the selection affected to only the paragraphs within the imgcontainer section/class.

Comment: thanks but when i write some less words in second div that is image 2 class it will align down little bit with the text and image see jsfiddle.net/archan/f0fsLd2h/3 so how i can do the same thing but with maintaining same level

Comment: @Arch Just add a min-height to the paragraph, and if needed use: overflow:auto;