# How to create text under background image in css

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://codepen.io/AakashL/pen/ZNzyqj">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://codepen.io/AakashL/pen/NVKvWX">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://codepen.io/AakashL/pen/BeBdad">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <p>Welcome to Top Imports! This website is created as an informational page which lays out the top and most popular Japanese imports of all time. Mainly of the cars that you will see in the content page will be older cars. All of these cars are iconic Japanese sports cars that are highly saught out for in the United States of America. I hope you enjoy the collection that we have put together. </p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {

  background-image: url("http://i67.tinypic.com/143dljp.png");
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;

}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: grey;
  padding: 0 35px
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

So I have a background image set in CSS however, I want to add text under an image, how exactly would I add text or content under the image?

This is how my webpage looks right now but I want the text to be under the image not through it:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665995 ?

Comment: The problem is that you have a navbar set at the top, and then just a body with a background-image (there is no image taking up space, as it is the background). Therefore your `<p>` section, actually begins at the top of the page just below the navbar.

Comment: If you want the text below the image, give your `<p>` tag a `margin-top` equal to the height of your background image. Or better still, give your `<p>` tag an id, and modify it's position that way.

Comment: Or you can replace the background on body by a div #main, define a height to this div and place the background here.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.background-image {
  background-image: url("http://oi67.tinypic.com/143dljp.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.under-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

ul {}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: grey;
  padding: 0 35px
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div class="background-image">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://codepen.io/AakashL/pen/ZNzyqj">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://codepen.io/AakashL/pen/NVKvWX">Content</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://codepen.io/AakashL/pen/BeBdad">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p class="under-text">Welcome to Top Imports! This website is created as an informational page which lays out the top and most popular Japanese imports of all time. Mainly of the cars that you will see in the content page will be older cars. All of these cars are iconic
      Japanese sports cars that are highly saught out for in the United States of America. I hope you enjoy the collection that we have put together. </p>
  </div>
```